# How can i convert my html view to pdf document

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am just new in MVC 3. I have a html view which contain all student related data. I just want to convert that view in a pdf  document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3) which illustrates how iTextSharp could be used to convert some **simple** HTML views to PDF by encapsulating the logic into a custom ActionResult. I cannot stress more on the word simple. Don't expect this to work with some complex HTML and CSS rules.

Comment: Thanks Darin !!! I have applied this one...but here pdfreportgenerator project is mandatory to include in our project.Than only we can access its method.Is there any simple approach where we can pass html view name from controller and it will generate pdf. If any than please Help !!! Thanks

Comment: @SonamMohite, there's nothing built-in .NET that allows you to generate PDF. So without a third party library I am afraid that you will have lots of difficulties generating PDF. So you will at least need iTextSharp. As far as the pdfreportgenerator project is concerned, well, you have its source code so you can directly include it in your project.

Comment: Darin i was exactly want to know this one...Thanks for this kind support.Now i come to know why i was getting difficulties.Thnks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to convert html to pdf.

Comment: Yeppp!!! Thanks Verkion. I have tried iTextSharp class to convert html to pdf but how exactly to do while i want to convert whole view to pdf. Please Help!!!

Comment: If you have tried using iTextSharp maybe you should ask a more specific question about troubleshooting your code instead of asking a general question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a product that I have used in the past, and it has worked out really well (EO.Pdf by EssentialObjects):

http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx